# How to validate an array of uploaded files?

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, yii

To validate a single file (a single input-file-field) is no problem in Yii and it works very well:

```
public function rules() {
    return CMap::mergeArray(parent::rules(), array(
        array(
            'image', 
            'file', 
            'allowEmpty'=>false, 
            'types'=>'pdf,jpg,gif,png', 
            'on' => 'CaseA, CaseB', 
            'maxSize'=>1024000, 
            'tooLarge' => 'Max File size is 1MB', 
            'message' => 'You have to upload a file at least'
        ),
        ....
        ....
```

What if image is an array of files? Created Form-Elements by Yii looks like this (Firebug-Output):

```
<input type="file" id="MyFormModel[image][0]" name="MyFormModel[image][0]">
<input type="file" id="MyFormModel[image][1]" name="MyFormModel[image][1]">
```

What exactly should I modify in my rules? A simple "image[]" does not help.

**EDIT: Solution**

```
public function rules() {
    return CMap::mergeArray(parent::rules(), array(
        array(
            'image', 
            'file', 
            'allowEmpty'=>false, 
            'types'=>'pdf,jpg,gif,png', 
            'on' => 'CaseA, CaseB', 
            'maxSize'=>1024000, 
            'maxFiles' => 5, // <----- THAT'S IT
            'tooLarge' => 'Max File size is 1MB', 
            'message' => 'You have to upload a file at least'
        ),
        ....
        ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`maxFiles`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#maxFiles-detail) attribute appropriately and the validator will work for all of the inputs. You don't need to change the input control names.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17103-solved-multiple-upload-validate/